# Usage of Superlative/Comparative for 2 Elements

Tags: superlatives, comparative

I would like to know what is a better way to say "top two".

I wrote 5 sentences. Please help me understand which is grammatically correct or a better way to explain this situation.

1. India and China have the largest number of people. The population of other country does not exceed theirs.
2. The populations of India and China both are about 1.4 billion. No other country has more people than them.
3. India and China are the two most populous countries in the world.
4. India and China are the top two countries with the largest population.
5. The largest number of people lives in India and China.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All five numbered items convey the same general idea, but some are more concise or clear than others. Option 3 is the most common and concise way to express that India and China are the two countries with the largest population.

Option 1 is grammatically correct, but it could be clearer. Instead of saying "The population of other country does not exceed theirs," you could say something like: "No other country has a larger population than India and China."

Option 2 is also grammatically correct, but it could be rephrased for clarity. For example, you could say: "Both India and China have a population of around 1.4 billion people."

Option 4 is a good option, but it might be more natural to say "India and China are the two countries with the largest populations" instead of "India and China are the top two countries with the largest population."

Option 5 is also grammatically correct, but it might not be the most concise or clear way to express this idea.

You might enjoy trying [the challenge on comparatives and superlatives](https://grammarerror.com/challenge/comparatives-and-superlatives) we have.

This account is affiliated with [grammarerror.com](https://grammarerror.com)